# How to get the number of the items via trigger

Tags: apex

I created a custom object sales agent, I want to count all the closed won opportunity that he has and displayed it in the sales agents object. How can I achieve this? this is my code please do edit it is incomplete

```
    trigger CountOpp on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
List<Franchise_Agent__c> agents = new List <Franchise_Agent__c>();
List<Franchise_Agent__c> agentsToUpdate = new List<Franchise_Agent__c>();
Set<ID> oppo_id = new Set<ID>();

for (Opportunity oppo : Trigger.new){
    if (oppo.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
    oppo_id.add(oppo.Franchise_Agent__c);

    agents = [SELECT Active__c,Id,Name,Total_Franchises_made__c,  Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c FROM Franchise_Agent__c WHERE Id = : oppo.id];
    }
    } 
for(Franchise_Agent__c franchise : agents){
    Integer closedWon = franchise.Opportunities.size();
    if(franchise.Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c != closedWon)
    {
    franchise.Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c = closedWon;
    agentsToUpdate.add(franchise);
}   
}
update agentsToUpdate;


}
```

Comment: Did you created the required look up field from 'Opportunity' to 'Sales Agent'?

Comment: yes. I created lookup from opportunity to sales agent where i get to pick a sales agent for my opportunity

Comment: If Roll-Up Summary field is disabled on 'Sales Agent' for some reason can you try creating a Formula field?

Comment: I also tried but There is no field that I can count. There is no opportunity when i create formula field on the sales agent

Comment: can you please help me with my code, I dont know how to continue. I need to count allthe closed opportunity of the sales agent.

Comment: There are apps that do custom rollup summaries if you don't want to write Apex.

Comment: I could use trigger but i dont know really how to code.. I have a code but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You've edited your question so many times that this post has became a mess, but here's my final suggestion, and I haven't tested this so it might require adaptation:

```
trigger CountOpp on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    //Get all the agents affected by the change in opportunities    
    List<Franchise_Agent__c> agents = [SELECT Id, Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c,
        (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities__r WHERE StageName='Closed Won') 
        FROM Franchise_Agent__c 
        WHERE Id IN (SELECT Franchise_Agent__c FROM Opportunity Where ID in :Trigger.new)];

    //get the list of agents that have the changed number of Franchises that are 'Closed Won'
    List<Franchise_Agent__c> agentsToUpdate = new List<Franchise_Agent__c>();

    for(Franchise_Agent__c a : agents ){
        Integer closedWon = a.Opportunities__r.size();
        if(a.Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c != closedWon)
        {
            a.Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c = closedWon;
            agentsToUpdate.add(a);
        }   
    }

    if(agentsToUpdate.size() > 0)
        update agentsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Did any of my answers help you? Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: please edit my code above.. it has error

Comment: @gelay Please see my updated code. I've just tested it myself and it correctly updates the 'Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c' field.

Comment: i have already a code but its not working please check

Comment: What's stopping you from using my trigger? In your code you are calling SOQL query in a FOR loop, and that should be avoided as there's a high possibility it will hit the Governor Limit. Can you please try my trigger or at least tell me why it is not suitable for you?

Answer (score -1):

Gelay,

Assuming that you want to show the total number of child records on parent record, follow this.

- Create a roll up summary field on parent object and relate it the
  child object
- Select 'Count' as roll up type
- Select criteria if any, to filter the child records. That is `SampleField = A` in your case.

Comment: I am on the custom object and i cannot create a roll up summary. It is somehow disabled. please read my question again i updated it.

Comment: @forcemars - that would require making the custom object the master in a M-D relationship to Opportunity, which is not possible. The solution will require writing Apex to perform the rollup.

Comment: @MikeChale. C'mon man, how can an opportunity be a 'Detail' object. I am totally aware of it. The initial question had no reference to either opportunity object nor had any details. Please view the history of question.
If I were you, I would personally double check before down voting. Good Day.

Comment: @Gelay, You should write a trigger on Opp object for the events After insert, After delete and After undelete. Take the COUNT() of the total closed won opp records related to THAT sales agent (get the sales agent id from the lookup field)  and update the field (create a new field TotalClosedWonOpp on franchise object) on the franchise object. I don't think you should face any issues.